# Try catch block issue

Tags: c#

The problem i'm having is every time i surround the (User is asked to enter info) with a try catch, so if they enter the wrong thing or push enter by mistake it will throw an error. When I do put the try catch it doesn't work it just ends the program. If i leave the try catch out like it is right now and the user just pushes enter it crashes the program..

```
namespace MaxHeartRate
```

{

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Display program instructions
        DisplayInstructions();

        // Collected user info
        CollectUserInfo();

    }
    static void DisplayInstructions()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("************************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("This program will Calculate your Max Heart Rate");
        Console.WriteLine("Also your Mininum and Maximum target Heart rate");
        Console.WriteLine("You will have to enter your info in when promted");
        Console.WriteLine("************************************************");
        return;
    }
    static void CollectUserInfo()
    {
        // Declar Variables
        string firstName, lastName;
        int birthYear = 0;
        int currentYear = 0;
        int age;
        double maxHeartRate, minTargetHeartRate, maxTargetHeartRate;

        try
        {
            // User is asked to enter info
            Console.Write("Enter your first Name: ");
            firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter your last name: ");
            lastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter the current year: ");
            currentYear = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter your birth year: ");
            birthYear = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            // Find Age
            age = findAge(currentYear, birthYear);

            // Find Max Heart rate
            maxHeartRate = findMaxHR(age);

            // Find Minimum Target Heart Rate
            minTargetHeartRate = findMinTHR(maxHeartRate);

            // Find Maximum Target Heart Rate
            maxTargetHeartRate = findMaxTHR(maxHeartRate);

            // Display Information
            DisplayInformation(firstName, lastName, age, maxHeartRate, minTargetHeartRate, maxTargetHeartRate);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please try again");
        }

        // Methods
    }
    static int findAge(int cYear, int bYear)
    {
        int age = cYear - bYear;
        return age;
    }
    static int findMaxHR(int age)
    {
        int MHR = 220 - age;
        return MHR;
    }
    static double findMinTHR(double maxHeartRate)
    {
        double minTHR = maxHeartRate * 0.50;
        return minTHR;
    }
    static double findMaxTHR(double maxHeartRate)
    {
        double maxTHR = maxHeartRate * 0.85;
        return maxTHR;
    }
    // Display information
    static void DisplayInformation(string firstName, string lastName, int age, double maxHeartRate, double minTargetHeartRate, double maxTargetHeartRate)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("************************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName + " You are " + age + " Years old" +
            "\n" + "\nYour Max Heart rate is " + maxHeartRate +
            " BPM" + "\n" + "\nYour Minimum Target Heart rate is " + minTargetHeartRate + " BPM" +
            "\n" + "\nwith a Maximum Target Heart rate of " + maxTargetHeartRate + " BPM");
        Console.WriteLine("************************************************");
        Console.Write("Push enter to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: IF you surround the code with try-catch it will jump to the catch if an error happens, so you need to somehow go back and ask again. Also, you can use `Int.TryParse` to avoid the try/catch

Comment: If you want help with your try/catch, why don't you show us how you implemented it????

Comment: Using a debugger usually rocks.

Comment: On a side note, you are not calculating _age_ in the way most people would expect. Most people born in December of, say, 2000, would not consider their age to be 17 at the moment, but only 16. Of course, this is, considering the use case, a detail. But asking the user about the current year is a bit much... "the computer" knows what year it is.

Comment: Yes i know asking for the current year is a bit much, But this is what my project asks for.. So i had to build it to what the teacher wants..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you're going to have to either define `currentYear` within the try/catch (both try and catch due to way the compiler interprets code paths) or upon declaration. Otherwise, you'll get `CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'currentYear'` at the line with `age = findAge(currentYear, birthYear)`

The following code works:

```
static void CollectUserInfo()
{
    // Declar Varibals
    string firstName, lastName;

    // We can define these here so that there isn't a compiler error.
    int birthYear = 0;
    int currentYear = 0;
    int age;
    double maxHeartRate, minTargetHeartRate, maxTargetHeartRate;

    // User is asked to enter info
    Console.Write("Enter your first Name: ");
    firstName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter your last name: ");
    lastName = Console.ReadLine();
    try
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the current year: ");
        currentYear = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter your birth year: ");
        birthYear = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    } 
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // The result of the error. 
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
        CollectUserInfo();
    }
    // Find Age
    age = findAge(currentYear, birthYear);

    // Find Max Heart rate
    maxHeartRate = findMaxHR(age);

    // Find Minimum Target Heart Rate
    minTargetHeartRate = findMinTHR(maxHeartRate);

    // Find Maximum Target Heart Rate
    maxTargetHeartRate = findMaxTHR(maxHeartRate);

    // Display Information
    DisplayInformation(firstName, lastName, age, maxHeartRate, minTargetHeartRate, maxTargetHeartRate);

// Methods
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I now see what i had wrong.. I first tried to surround the whole thing with a try catch. Then I did surround just the currentYear and birthyear but it was throwing the error. I see having declaring the variables together caused a problem.. Thanks for the help guys..

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how you can get valid input from user with retry attempts:

```
int currentYear;
while (true)
{
    var currentYearText = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(currentYearText, out currentYear))
    {
        // User entered a valid integer
        // Validating that integer
        if (currentYear > 2000 && currentYear < 2050)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    Console.Write("Please enter valid year between 2000 and 2050");
}
```

If user enters invalid data, he will be asked to try again. If user input is valid, code will get out of the loop and go to the next statement.